# XAML Rotate and Fade Out Animation Together

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation

I have the following code for Image Rotation Animation :

```
<Image Source="/Resources/Collage5.jpg" Name="myImage">

    <!--Code for Rotation Animation-->
    <!--RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">-->
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform/>
    </Image.RenderTransform>

    <Image.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)" To="360" Duration="0:0:5" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Image.Triggers>
```

and the following code for Fade Out animation:

```
 <StackPanel>
        <Image Name="MyRectangle" Source="/Resources/Collage5.jpg">
            <Image.Triggers>

     <!--Animates the rectangle's opacity.--> 

                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetName="MyRectangle" 
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:5"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Image.Triggers>
        </Image>
    </StackPanel>
```

Now, what I want to do is, make the Image rotate once and then apply rotation and fade out effect together so that by the time one rotation is complete the image has faded out completely.
How do I achieve this?

Comment: You have two images here. Do you want to apply the second rotation and fading to the second image?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution . I used the BeginTime tag to start the second animation after the first.